EKF_filter_node is unable to calculate the position
i am a beginner to ros2 and currently iam trying fuse imu data and odometry data together to get a good estimate of the robots postion (a two wheel differential drive). but the filters output estimating that it is moving even the bot is completely stationary and the filter output seems noisy.the parameters provided for the node are mentioned below. please let me know how to solve this or my understanding about the filter is wrong.`ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:
frequency: 10.0
two_d_mode: true
publish_tf: true
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_footprint_ekf
world_frame: odom
odom0: /bot_one/odom_msgs_noisy
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_config: [false,false,false,
               false,false,true,
               true,false,true,
               true,false,true,
               false,false,false]
odom0_differential: true

imu0: /imu_ekf
imu0_queue_size: 10

imu0_config: [false,false,false,
              false,false,true,
              false,false,false,
              true,false,true,
              true,true,true]

imu0_differential: false

this is the code of my controller (deliberately added some gaussian noise)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
import math
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
import numpy as np
from rclpy.time import Time
from rclpy.constants import S_TO_NS
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf_transformations import quaternion_from_euler
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster

class NoisyController(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('noisy_controller') #type:ignore

        self.declare_parameter("wheel_radius",0.033)
        self.declare_parameter("wheel_seperation",0.17)

        self.wheel_radius = self.get_parameter("wheel_radius").get_parameter_value().double_value
        self.wheel_seperation = self.get_parameter("wheel_seperation").get_parameter_value().double_value

        self.get_logger().info('''wheel radius is set to : %f \n wheel seperation is set to : %f ''' %(self.wheel_radius,self.wheel_seperation))

        self.left_wheel_prev_pos_= 0.0
        self.right_wheel_prev_pos_= 0.0
        self.prev_time_ = self.get_clock().now()
        
        self.theta = 0.0
        self.x_ = 0.0
        self.y_ = 0.0

        self.joint_sub_ = self.create_subscription(JointState,"/joint_states",self.JointStateCallback,10)
        self.odom_pub = self.create_publisher(Odometry,"bot_one/odom_msgs_noisy",10)
        
        self.odom_msg_ = Odometry()
        self.odom_msg_.header.frame_id = "odom"
        self.odom_msg_.child_frame_id = "base_footprint_ekf"
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

        self.br_ = TransformBroadcaster(self)
        self.transform_stamped_ = TransformStamped()
        self.transform_stamped_.header.frame_id = "odom"
        self.transform_stamped_.child_frame_id = "base_footprint_noisy"

    def JointStateCallback(self,msg):

        wheel_left_encoder = msg.position[1] + np.random.normal(0,0.005)
        wheel_right_encoder = msg.position[0] + np.random.normal(0,0.005)
        dp_left = wheel_left_encoder - self.left_wheel_prev_pos_
        dp_right = wheel_right_encoder - self.right_wheel_prev_pos_
        dt = Time.from_msg(msg.header.stamp) - self.prev_time_

        d_s = (self.wheel_radius * dp_right + self.wheel_radius * dp_left) / 2
        d_theta = (self.wheel_radius * dp_right - self.wheel_radius * dp_left)/ self.wheel_seperation
        self.theta += d_theta
        self.x_ += d_s * math.cos(self.theta)
        self.y_ += d_s * math.sin(self.theta)

        left_ang_v = dp_left/(dt.nanoseconds/S_TO_NS)
        right_ang_v = dp_right/(dt.nanoseconds/S_TO_NS)

        linear_v = (self.wheel_radius * right_ang_v + self.wheel_radius * left_ang_v)/2
        angular_v =(self.wheel_radius * right_ang_v - self.wheel_radius * left_ang_v)/ self.wheel_seperation

        q = quaternion_from_euler(0 ,0 ,self.theta)
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.x = q[0]
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.y = q[1]
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.z = q[2]
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.orientation.w = q[3]
        self.odom_msg_.header.stamp=self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.position.x = self.x_
        self.odom_msg_.pose.pose.position.y = self.y_
        self.odom_msg_.twist.twist.linear.x = linear_v
        self.odom_msg_.twist.twist.angular.z = angular_v

        self.transform_stamped_.transform.translation.x = self.x_
        self.transform_stamped_.transform.translation.y = self.y_
        self.transform_stamped_.transform.rotation.x = q[0]
        self.transform_stamped_.transform.rotation.y = q[1]
        self.transform_stamped_.transform.rotation.z = q[2]
        self.transform_stamped_.transform.rotation.w = q[3]
        self.transform_stamped_.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()

        # self.get_logger().info("linear velocity :%f \n angular velocity : %f"%(linear_v,angular_v))
        self.left_wheel_prev_pos_ = msg.position[1] 
        self.right_wheel_prev_pos_ = msg.position[0] 
        self.prev_time_ = Time.from_msg(msg.header.stamp)
        self.br_.sendTransform(self.transform_stamped_)
        self.odom_pub.publish(self.odom_msg_)

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    noisy_ctrl = NoisyController()
    rclpy.spin(noisy_ctrl)
    noisy_ctrl.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

please refere the below link for the plotjuggler graphs and others
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11SssRhSl17MGYd_oD9_DrWEf4-c38JSW?usp=sharing
